# Importing Excel files with a large number of columns header into mysql with c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio-2010, excel-2010

i just was just wondering, how do i import large excel files into mysql with c#? My coding experience isn't great and i was hoping if there's anyone out there who could give me some rough idea to start on it. So far, i was able to load excel files into datagridview with the following codes:

```
string PathConn = " Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathTextBox.Text + ";Extended Properties =\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathConn);
conn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + loadTextBox.Text + "$]", conn);
table = new DataTable();             

myDataAdapter.Fill(table);
```

but after that, i don't know how i could extract the information and save it into mysql database. Assuming i have a empty scheme created before, how do i work on uploading excel files into mysql? thanks.

Comment: You may find this useful given you have gotten as far as getting the data into a `DataTable`: http://code.google.com/p/mysqlbulkcopy/

Comment: hey there, i have gone through the website a few days ago but i do not know how it works, is there any way you could provide me some assistance??

Answer (score 0):

I think you would then need to loop over the items in the datatable and do something with them (maybe an insert statement to your DB)

like so

```
foreach(DataRow dr in table.Rows)
{
    string s = dr[0].ToString() // this will be the first column in the datatabl as they are zero indexed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what i do in data migration scenarios from one SQL Server to another or DataFiles to SQL:

1. Create the new Table on the destination SQL Server (Column names, Primary Key etc.)
2. Load existing Data into a DataTable (Thats what you did already)
3. Now Query the new Table with the DataAdapter into another DataTable (Same as you did with the excel file except you now query the SQL Table.)
4. Load OldData from 'table' into 'newTable' using DataTable Method "Load()"

```cs
string PathConn = (MYSQL Connection String goes here)
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathConn);
conn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + loadTextBox.Text + "$]", conn);
newTable = new DataTable();             

myDataAdapter.Fill(newTable); 

Now use the Load() Method on the new table:

newTable.Load(table.CreateDataReader(), <Specify LoadOption here>)
```

Matching columns will be imported into the new DataTable. (You can ensure the mapping through using Aliases in the select statements)

After Loading the existing Data into the new Table you will be able to use an DataAdapter to write the changes back to database.

Example for writing data back: ConnString - connection String for DB,
SelectStmt (can use the same as you did on the empty Table before) and provide the newTable as dtToWrite

```
public static void writeDataTableToServer(string ConnString, string selectStmt, DataTable dtToWrite)
    {
        using (OdbcConnection odbcConn = new OdbcConnection(ConnString))
        {
            odbcConn.Open();

            using (OdbcTransaction trans = odbcConn.BeginTransaction())
            {
                using (OdbcDataAdapter daTmp = new OdbcDataAdapter(selectStmt, ConnString))
                {
                    using (OdbcCommandBuilder cb = new OdbcCommandBuilder(daTmp))
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            cb.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges;
                            daTmp.UpdateBatchSize = 5000;
                            daTmp.SelectCommand.Transaction = trans;
                            daTmp.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 120;
                            daTmp.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();
                            daTmp.InsertCommand.Transaction = trans;
                            daTmp.InsertCommand.CommandTimeout = 120;
                            daTmp.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
                            daTmp.UpdateCommand.Transaction = trans;
                            daTmp.UpdateCommand.CommandTimeout = 120;
                            daTmp.DeleteCommand = cb.GetDeleteCommand();
                            daTmp.DeleteCommand.Transaction = trans;
                            daTmp.DeleteCommand.CommandTimeout = 120;
                            daTmp.Update(dtToWrite);
                            trans.Commit();
                        }
                        catch (OdbcException ex)
                        {
                            trans.Rollback();
                            throw ex;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            odbcConn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Primary Key on the newTable is necessary, otherwise you might get a CommandBuilder exception.

BR

Therak

Comment: sorry but i do not get the part <Specify loadOption here>. And the code above does not have any line that includes insert, i'm sorry but i thought i have to use insert statement to insert new information into the database, correct me if i'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the late response - was on vacation. <Specify loadOption> ment that you have to choose a LoadOption. In VS you will see how they will behave on the LoadOption. It determines how the loaded data will be inserted into the DataTable(Which Row Version will be overwritten).  Concerning the Insert statement: An ODBCCommandBuilder will automatically generate the propert SQL Statements for you - if you provided Primary Key Informationen on the Database. Hope this helps a little bit more.. BR

Answer (score 0):

Your halfway there, You have obtained the information from the Excel spreadsheet and have it stored in a **DataTable**.

The first thing you need to do before you look to import a significant amount of data into SQL is validate what you have read in from the spreadsheets.

You have a few options, one of which is do something very similar to how you read in your data and that is use a **SQLAdapter** to perform am **INSERT** into the SQL Database. All your really needing to do in this case is create a new connection and write the **INSERT** command.

There are many example of doing this on here.

Another option which i would use, is **LINQ to CSV** (http://linqtocsv.codeplex.com/).

With this you can load all of your data into class objects which makes it easier to validate each object before you perform your **INSERT** into **SQL**.

If you have limited experience then use the SQLAdapter to connect to you DB.

Good Luck

Comment: if i were to write a insert command, that wouldn't be a good way to code, sorry that i failed to mention this previously was that, the excel file does not always contain the same column header, sometimes it can be filled with less information (columns header) and sometimes it can be more. So there will be different schema to cater for different information. But if i were to use insert, i would have to key in one by one and that is not very ideal, do u have any other way for the code to check itself?