# Transferring data from an Excel file into a MySQL table

Tags: c#, mysql

I have an Excel 2003 spreadsheet that I need to import into MySQL.  I have a table called `dev_products` with two fields; product_id and product_description.  The Excel file has exactly the same column structure - but I don't know how to transfer the data (through code - as I will have to do this again).

I am able to connect to the file....but that's about as far as I have got....and I really need some help.

Thanks - as always.

```
    const string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + strExcelFilenameandLocation + "; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
    OleDbConnection xlConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    xlConn.Open();

    string strQuery = "??????????";

    var con = new MySqlConnection(ClsVariables.StrDb);
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(strQuery, con);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    xlConn.Close();
```

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19133317/2655508 the question shows you how it is done. If you only need some columns, be sure to put them between []. Keep in mind this is for the excel part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the excel file in csv

1. Direct insert to db using mysql bulk insert
   [BULK INSERT in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330314/bulk-insert-in-mysql)
2. Read the data from csv using the function given below
   The function will return the data in DataTable
   Extract the data and create mysql query to insert in db

   ```
   using System.IO;
   using System.Windows.Forms;
   using System.Data;
   public class readCSV
   {
   public DataTable getDataTable()
   {
       DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
       try
       {
           using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(this.filename))
           {
               string line;
               string[] row;
               int rowcount = 0;
               DataRow dRow;

               while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
               {
                   row = line.Split(',');
                   dRow = dTable.NewRow();

                   for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
                   {
                       if (rowcount == 0)
                       {
                           dTable.Columns.Add(row[i]);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           dRow[dTable.Columns[i]] = row[i];
                       }
                   }

                   if (rowcount != 0)
                   {
                       dTable.Rows.Add(dRow);
                   }
                   rowcount++;
               }
           }
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
       }

       return dTable;
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much - that was a really big help.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to directly import using sql command

Save as text (CSV) and use LOAD DATA INFILE LOCAL in the mysql command line client to load the file ...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

--

Ref : http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?32,216343,216344#msg-216344